# Why doesn't my Spring-based web application respond to its defined endpoints

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty

I'm developing a simple Spring-based web service `userSetting` to run on Liberty 8.5.5.9.  I'm able to build and deploy the service, and when I start it, it appears to understand its context root (`userSetting`) but none of its endpoints; I believe I'm missing some essential Spring-based linkage of the parts of the application, but can't figure out which.

The main class of the application looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-resource1.xml")
@Import({RESTInterface.class})
public class UserSettingApplication {

  private static final LoggerUtils logger = new LoggerUtils( UserSettingApplication.class );

  public static void main(String[] args) {
          logger.debug( "Entering UserSettingApplication.main()" );
          System.out.println( "Entering UserSettingApplication.main()" );
    SpringApplication.run(UserSettingApplication.class, args);
          logger.debug( "Exiting UserSettingApplication.main()" );
          System.out.println( "Exiting UserSettingApplication.main()" );
 }

  // Dan Vega says:  Remember that this going to execute after the 
  // application context is loaded so you could use it to check if 
  // certain beans exist or what values of certain properties are. 

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

      logger.info("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

      String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
      Arrays.sort(beanNames);
      for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        logger.info(beanName);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and the class that defines the endpoints (abbreviated to a single end point) is:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "userSetting")
public class RESTInterface {
        ...

        @RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public String hello() {
                return "Hello, dude!";
        }

}
```

when I try to hit the endpoint `http://localhost:9080/userSetting/userSetting/hello`, I get the message:

```
Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /userSetting/hello
```

It *appears* that the `RestController` has not gotten properly hooked up to the application; in desperation, I tried adding the following line to the main class:

```
@Import({RESTInterface.class})
```

but this didn't change anything.  Can someone please tell me how to properly connect in the endpoints?

Comment: If you are running it inside of the Liberty change the class definition to extend SpringBootServletInitializer like this  `UserSettingApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer` and override `configure` method

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting http://localhost:9080/userSetting/hello
You are giving 'userSetting' twice in the url